# Apache Repo Server alternative

Tags: java, maven

I currently working with Maven and some Repos.
When i build my Project via Travis CI i get an 503 Error on an Repo.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project RadioBots: Could not resolve dependencies for project RadioBots:RadioBots:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.sedmelluq:lavaplayer:jar:1.3.48: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.sedmelluq:lavaplayer:jar:1.3.48: Could not transfer artifact com.sedmelluq:lavaplayer:pom:1.3.48 from/to sonatype-apache (https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/): Transfer failed for https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/com/sedmelluq/lavaplayer/1.3.48/lavaplayer-1.3.48.pom 503 Service Unavailable -> [Help 1]
```

On the Website it says "Service Unavailable". The Uptime Site for The Apache Repo Server is also Red marked.

Is there any alternative Server that i can use? Maby a Backup Server oder a clone?
If there is something like that, how can i bind my Project to this Server?
Is there a way to do this in the pom.xml?

Comment: There is maven.org, Google provides mirrors. Mirrors are configured in mavens settings.xml. Simply google for lavaplayer and you will get a list of mirrors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various other repositories that may contain your dependencies e.g. [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter). See [Using Mirrors for Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) and hope that your dependencies were mirrored somewhere.

To protect against remote repository being down or worse, dependencies being deleted from the remote repository one usually caches them locally. This can be done in few ways e.g. by hosting your own proxy repository (e.g. by using [Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/)) or by caching build dependencies on the CI (e.g. see [Travis CI docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/)).